# Python: Read file with list as list

Tags: python

I have placed a list in a text file. I want python to read the text file and return the contents as a list. However, it is instead reading the content as a string:

Text file:

```
['a','b','c']
```

Python:

```
ids=[]

writtenFile =open('file.txt')
readFile=writtenFile.read()
ids= readFile
writtenFile.close()
print ids
```

What is returned is ['a','b','c'] as a string, not as a list or just text. Is there a way I can retrieve ['a','b','c'] from the text file and then store this in the ids string so that ids is a list ['a','b','c'] and not the string ? "['a','b','c']"?

Comment: `I have placed a list in a text file` why would you do that?

Comment: @njzk2 but what is the problem with that, he wants to know how to convert into python list object from string.

Comment: If you must know, I have 3 scripts that must use the same list of thousands of items. I want the first script to create the list, then save to a file that the other scripts can read

Comment: in python there are better mechanism to save data to a file. `picke` is made for that. Other cross platform format such as json also exist. The problem with your approach is that you are relying on the string representation of the object, and hoping it actually represents the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ast.literal_eval` to literally evaluate the contents of file as is written though really a string:

```
data = ast.literal_eval(open('data.txt').read()) # create file, read contents, evaluate
```

Comment: Be sure to `import ast` so that you can use `literal_eval`

Answer (score 1):

If you just have the same format the quickest way would be just to strip and split:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    print(f.readline().translate(None,"'[]\n").split(","))
    ['a', 'b', 'c']
```